# Designing an XML reader

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I've assigned the task to create a class structure for an xml reader! What I've got so far is that there are two main classes for a simple xml file. elements and attributes.I can use the inbuilt c# xml reader to read a xml file! but my code should be able to identify the xml elements, there structure,as well as the attributes.. I've so far identified the main two classes but I'm stuck on this now. if some one can explain a possible theory or a method since  I'm new to programming, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to write this? The .NET framework already has excellent support for this task, see [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Comment: it's actually a task assigned to me to get a better idea of OOP programming! :(

Comment: In that case, I suggest you complete that assignment on your own, otherwise it would somehow be pointless. If you still want to cheat, simply look at the class hierarchy of `XDocument`.

Comment: I don't want to cheat! I want some sort of guidelines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a XML reader and a XML document. 
They are modeled after different patterns.

The reader in .NET is made just to read a stream and stop when it encounters some element / attribute or other type of node. This may be practical if you want to be fast or you have a large stream that you don't want to keep in memory.

The XML document reads the entire stream and instantiates an object model that represents it. 
This is practical if the you need to know the structure and it fits into memory.

If you are to implement the reader you could crate methods like ReadNext() which would read and return the next node it finds. For starters I would stick with parsing xml elements and their attributes, not comments, namespaces and other more difficult things.

Answer (score 0):

These are three very good examples on how to design an "XML reader" in an OOP way:

- [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)
- [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

They map an XML document, the parts a XML document consists of and the structure of an XML document to a structure of corresponding classes and they introduce means to build and analyse an XML document.

If you want to excercise and build your own class structure without "cheating" (i.e. looking how others did it), you could start by examining the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) and identify the elements/parts an XML document can consist of (Elements, Attributes, DataTypes etc.) it is likely that many of those elements should have corresponding classes in your design. Next you have to think what you want to be able to ***do*** with the XML. This will also influence your design.

As a general rule you should always keep in mind that the resulting API should be easy to use. Your target "audience" will probably be developers who know XML so your classes should reflect what they know about XML (names should be similar etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should use well established API to serve your purpose . Apart from it , i think you can use chain of responsibility design pattern .